# Can you build all targets and platforms in a single step using the C++ Builder IDE?

Tags: c++builder

In Visual studio you can use `Build` / `Batch Build` to build everything at once, is there an option similar in C++ Builder?

TIA!!

Comment: If you create a separate project for each target then you can use the "build all projects" menu item which builds all the projects in a single project group with one click. But this approach may not be ideal because it means maintaining different projects that are identical apart from the build settings (ie apart from the target). Really you need a command to build all targets for a single project. Currently (version Alexandria 11.3) there is not such a feature.

Comment: @RogerCigol "*Currently (version Alexandria 11.3) there is not such a feature*" - yes, there is. This can be done using [Build Groups](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Build_Groups)